# Live update Pie Chart

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create very useful and easy way to live update Pie chart. For example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));

        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        final Label caption = new Label("");
        caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
        caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");

        for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData()) {
            data.getNode().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            caption.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX());
                            caption.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY());
                            caption.setText(String.valueOf(data.getPieValue())
                                + "%");
                        }
                    });
        }

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(chart, caption);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I display the chart I want to call Java Method and update the chart like this:

```
PieChartUpdate(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree);
```

Can you show me how I can edit the code in order to make the live updates more easy to use?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems did you run in to while you were trying it?

Comment: I'm voting up because the idea it is interesting, but the question is too homework-ish. Most likely you should set new values on the chart, then layout the whole thing again. But I don't have knowledge of the JavaFX APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as i could see, all classes that are used to establish a `PieChart`, like `PieChart.Data` and of course the `ObservableList` are already designed so that they will update the `PieChart` the moment something changes, be it the list itself or values inside the `Data` Objects. See [the binding chapters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) how this is done. But you don't need to write your own bindings for the `PieChart`.

The code below should do what you want. Use `addData(String name, double value)` to create a new `Data` object for your pie chart, or update an existing one which has the same `name` like the first parameter of the method. The `PieChart` will automatically play a animation when changes are made to the list (new `Data` object added) or a `Data` object got changed.

```
 //adds new Data to the list
public void naiveAddData(String name, double value)
{
    pieChartData.add(new Data(name, value));
}

//updates existing Data-Object if name matches
public void addData(String name, double value)
{
    for(Data d : pieChartData)
    {
        if(d.getName().equals(name))
        {
            d.setPieValue(value);
            return;
        }
    }
    naiveAddData(name, value);
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete code? This `pieChartData` is not correct.

Comment: I think you can do that on your own. Declare `pieChartData` as a new attribute of the class `MainApp`. This is just a minor change to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone feels extremely lost and isn't sure how to implement denhackl's answer, here is a working version of what he tried to explain.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LivePie extends Application {

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);

       this.pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       addData("Test", 5.1);
       addData("Test2", 15.1);
       addData("Test3", 3.1);
       addData("Test1", 4.9);
       addData("Test2", 15.1);
       addData("Test3", 2.1);
       addData("Test5", 20.1);


        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        final Label caption = new Label("");
        caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
        caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");



        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(chart, caption);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void naiveAddData(String name, double value)
    {
        pieChartData.add(new javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data(name, value));
    }

    //updates existing Data-Object if name matches
    public void addData(String name, double value)
    {
        for(javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data d : pieChartData)
        {
            if(d.getName().equals(name))
            {
                d.setPieValue(value);
                return;
            }
        }
        naiveAddData(name, value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Many thanks to the creator of the topic and the answers provided!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good introductory article on using properties and binding.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm